# eps-converted-to.pdf not found

Tags: graphics, luatex, eps

I was trying to include a figure in LuaLatex, but got an error message of

> `!Package pdftex.def Error: File 'test-eps-converted-to.pdf' not found.`

The same code run in pdfLaTex+MakeIndex+bibTex. Is there a way to fix this? Also, is there anyway to include a directory or file pathway that contains a white space (e.g., c:\my project\tex)?

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor,colortbl}    
\usepackage{epstopdf,epsfig}    
\begin{document}    
\begin{figure}    
\includegraphics{test.eps}    
\end{figure}    
\end{document}
```

Comment: You could try to remove the `eps` extension from the `\includegraphics` command.

Comment: You have to call `lualatex` with the command line option `--shell-escape`

Comment: Thanks. I tried removing the eps extension-now it shows "!LaTex Error: File 'test" not found". I put the .eps file in the same directory as the .tex file. Also, how can option --shell-escape be called for lualatex?

Comment: From the command line `lualatex --shell-escape myfile` where `myfile` is the name of your `.tex` file. If you want to do that from your editor add `--shell-escape` to the command line of `lualatex`.

Comment: Can you please post more details? Is the command line in .tex file?

Comment: @user36969 First of all, if you want to notify me, start the comment with `@` followed by my name. Then you have to tell me which OS and editor you are using.

Comment: @karlkoeller The `--shell-escape` option shouldn't be needed, unless the version of `luatex` is rather old.

Comment: @egreg I think the one that comes with MiKTeX _is_ rather old. In fact, without `--shell-escape` I get the same error...

Comment: @karlkoeller What version number does it advertise?

Comment: @egreg `Version beta-0.76.0-2013062820 (rev 4627)`

Comment: @karlkoeller It's the same as on my TeX Live 2013.

Comment: @egreg Then again problems with LuaTeX in MiKTeX...

Comment: Thanks everyone! I tried the same code in xeLaTex, and it worked! This is indeed a problem with LuaLaTex

Comment: @user36969 We use the package `epstopdf` with pdfTeX and LuaTeX (based on pdfTeX) to include EPS image because these two engines do not support EPS image directly. This package will try to call the program named `epstopdf` to convert EPS image file to PDF version. According to the ERROR message, I suppose that you did not install that program correctly---you can type `epstopdf` in terminal window to test it. If system says `epstopdf is not a executable` or something like, then you may need to install it manually.

Comment: no, you have to write this in the terminal. Go to the directory, where the .tex file is located with cd and then write the command line lualatex --shell-escape myfile

Comment: @karlkoeller Can you confirm whether the issue is still present in MiKTeX? If not, it's better to close this question.

Comment: @egreg This problem with LuaTeX is still there...

Comment: Try to remove the extension `.eps` and rename `test-eps-converted-to.pdf` to `test.pdf`.

Comment: I think this question should be closed. I compiled an example with `pdflatex`, `lualatex`, and `xelatex` and all worked fine. I'm on `TeX Live 2015`.

Comment: @Jost MikTeX still has the problem. Please don't make too hasty vote decisions

Comment: @percusse It works with `--shell-restricted`.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Yes but that was available neither in the question nor the comments and I was writing a half-baked answer. Would you like to write one as you are more qualified to cook-up one?

Comment: @percusse Something for MiKTeX experts. Maybe, it is a bug to use a different setting for shell escape than TeX Live, or it's a feature that the shell escape is turned off by default for security reasons.